# Adding new element by clicking submit

Tags: javascript

I've two divs which collect strings and numbers. What should I do to allow adding more than only one element in my div?

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.buttonClass');
let ctn1 = document.querySelector('.ctn1');
let ctn2 = document.querySelector('.ctn2');


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;

  if (!isNaN(parseInt(myValue))) {
    ctn1.innerHTML = myValue;
  } else if (typeof myValue == 'string') {
    ctn2.innerHTML = myValue;
  }

  document.querySelector('.inputClass').value = "";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class='inputClass' />
<input type="button" value="Wyślij" class="buttonClass" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-2">
    <p class="ctn1">Tu będzie number</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <p class="ctn2">Tu będzie string</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [addition assignment operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) (+=) which adds new value in addition to the older value.

For eg: A change from `abc.innerHTML = myValue;` to `abc.innerHTML += myValue;` to stop overriding the innerhtml content.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.buttonClass');
let ctn1 = document.querySelector('.ctn1');
let ctn2 = document.querySelector('.ctn2');


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;

    if(!isNaN(parseInt(myValue))){
        ctn1.innerHTML += myValue;
    } else if (typeof myValue == 'string') {
        ctn2.innerHTML += myValue;
    }

    document.querySelector('.inputClass').value = "";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class='inputClass' />
<input type="button" value="Wyślij" class="buttonClass"/>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="container-2">
    <p class="ctn1">Tu będzie number: </p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-2">
    <p class="ctn2">Tu będzie string: </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly your requirement is. Still, I am trying to provide you an answer based on my understanding of the question.
It seems you want to add a new item (number or string) every time you hit the `Submit` button. Keeping this in mind, I edited your code in the following manner:

**The HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" class='inputClass' />`
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="buttonClass" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-2">
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript Code:**

```
let button = document.querySelector('.buttonClass');
let containers = document.getElementsByClassName('container-2');
let container1 = containers[0];
let container2 = containers[1];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;

  let para = document.createElement("p");
    let node = document.createTextNode(myValue);

  if (!isNaN(parseInt(myValue))) {
    container1.appendChild(node);
  } else if (typeof myValue == 'string') {
    container2.appendChild(node);
  }

  document.querySelector('.inputClass').value = "";
});
```

**Explanation:**
I am searching all `<div>` elements based on the class `container-2` and based on your logic of identifying the `type` of input value I am adding a new `<p>` HTML element as a child to the respective `<div>` element.
I am putting the JSFiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/110691/) so that you can test it.